# Text appears on top of the page and I want it on the center

Tags: spacing, indentation

I have added a quote at the beginning of my thesis as follows:

```
\newpage

\enquote{\itshape Illud in his rebus non est mirabile, quare, omnia cum rerum primordia sint in motu, summa tamen summa uideatur stare quiete [...]
Omnis enim longe nostris ab sensibus infra primorum natura iacet; quapropter, ubi ipsa cernere iam nequeas, motus quoque surpere debent.} \bigbreak

\hfill Lucretius, \textit{De Rerum Natura}, Liber Secundus, 310
```

Problem is, the quote appears on top of the page, and I want it to appear on the center (with an upper indent, you could say). I have tried with \vspace but it does nothing. How can I achieve that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \enquote{\itshape Illud in his rebus non est mirabile, quare, omnia cum rerum primordia sint in motu, summa tamen summa uideatur stare quiete [...]
    Omnis enim longe nostris ab sensibus infra primorum natura iacet; quapropter, ubi ipsa cernere iam nequeas, motus quoque surpere debent.} \bigbreak
    
    \hfill Lucretius, \textit{De Rerum Natura}, Liber Secundus, 310
    \vspace{\fill}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

The difference between `\vspace` and `\vspace*` is that the latter generates vertical space that's not discardable; see https://latexref.xyz/_005cvspace.html for some more information.

Comment: Thanks, this completely fixed it for me!

Comment: *tips hat* You're welcome!